# Java execute shell command - error [Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified]

Tags: java, python, shell

I want to execute the python script from java using shell commands
file location: d:/python/test.py

below is my java program

```
def callstme(){
        Process p
        try {

            List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
            cmdList.add("sh");
            cmdList.add("d:/python/test.py");
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
            p = pb.start();

            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
             p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

while executing I'm getting the error

```
"java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

Comment: The problem appears to be that the system is unable to resolve `sh` to an executable file or script or whatever.  Maybe the directory containing `sh` command is not in the `PATH` ... that is being passed in the child process environment.  Maybe `sh` is not installed.  (You appear to be using Windows!!)  Maybe it is a permissions problem of some kind.  Try using the absolute path for the `sh` command instead.  (Typically `/bin/sh` ... on a UNIX / Linux system.)  Or on Windows ... maybe you should be using `cmd.exe` instead of `sh`?